# How to setup virtualization for our Servers / WorkStations?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v, remote-desktop, vdi

I need to setup the virtual environment for our Servers and around 10 workstations. At present, we are connecting to the servers or workstations through Windows Remote Desktop Connection ( mstsc ) on Internet.

I came across the products such as hyper-v, VMWare, XenServer  but completely new to enter into one of these platform.

Comment: You should really spend a lot more time researching the technologies and even consider talking to some of the companies or their VAR network. This really isn't something we can really help you with at this with your current knowledgebase.

Comment: I have removed the VDI, Please share your answers rather than remarks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't just *jump in* to VDI as your first virtualization product. VDI typically builds on many complementary technologies, such as the hypervisor, the management suite for that hypervisor, VM images and templates, linked-clones, IP pools, etc.

If you're completely new to virtualization, I'd recommend installing Hyper-V or VMware ESXi in a test lab, and playing with VMM or vCenter respectively. Once you understand that, you can start bolting on some of the VDI solutions available, such as VMware Horizon View if you're using VMware or Microsoft's Remote Desktop Services with Desktop Pools if you're using Hyper-V. Then, you should take what you've learned and virtualize your servers first. After a year or so of understanding how this works, you'll be well equipped to jump into VDI.

If you need this on a quicker timeline, I'd recommend hiring a consulting firm that specializes in this to assist you. It'll save you quite a bit of headache. What you're asking is roughly the equivalent of "I've seen a keyboard before, how can I develop an e-commerce site?"

---

Edit for future visitors: This question used to ask about how to configure VDI without having any virtualization experience. The OP has since edited it, making this answer seem a little out of place, but I'm leaving it as it answered the question as originally asked.

Comment: I have removed the VDI, kindly share the suggestions to move forward

Comment: in my situation we have 10 windows desktops and 4 windows servers. Please suggest one specific software, which i can research and get into it

Comment: I suggest you read about the strengths and weaknesses of each platform and choose which one suits your needs. No one can pick for you based off of two paragraphs on Server Fault.

Comment: i agree with you. i wish to write 1000 lines. but i am completely new to this technology. i am from .net programming background. kindly share one specific virtualization software which i can get into it.

Comment: also as you said on your answer after spending a year on how this works and then jump into VDI. we dont have much time. also, we dont have much fund to hire a consultant. we are trying to learn and utilize the best we can.

Comment: MDMarra mentioned the two major players in his post: Microsoft Hyper-V, and VMware ESXi.  Both offer free versions which have excellent functionality for small environments. Either could potentially work for your purposes.

Comment: @jlehtinen ,thank you. I will discuss with my manager about VMware ESXi.  Will see, how it goes. Thank you all

Comment: Amazon offers virtual desktops with pricing similar to their other AWS products. Judging by your lack of experience and lack of funding to bring an experienced engineer into this project, Amazon hosted desktops may be a better approach.

Comment: sure @MDMarra !!! Rome was not build in a day. Keep learning , Thank you